# background pegando toda section

Tags: html5, css3

Meu background está pegando toda minha section
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo limitar o inicio dele? Por exemplo fazendo com que o background roxo inicie na linha vermelha
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<section class="video-container">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe
      width="800"
      height="450"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/befv1AwaYMs"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```

Css

```
.video-container{
padding: 1rem calc((100% - 1024px ) /2);
background: rebeccapurple ;
```

}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um outro elemento para fazer o background. Assim a cor virá dele, e não da section.
HTML:

```
<div class='video-container'>
   <div class='background'></div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container{
  border: blue solid 1px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

.background{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Usando o position relative no container pai, e absolute no filho, o filho se comporta como se fosse fixed, assim, quando o background do filho for usado, pode ser controlado pelo tamanho e pela sua posição em relação ao pai. Veja que o filho está com `top:50%;`, isso quer dizer que ele começa na metade do elemento pai, e como sua altura é a própria metade do elemento pai, o background fica apenas em baixo. Você pode ir variando a posição e altura, até chegar no que deseja.